# Kendo UI Grid Widget client-side filtering on numeric column

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have the below model schema for a field in my Kendo UI grid widget:

```
RS_LookBackDays: { type: "number", editable: true },
```

The columns configuration for the same is :

```
{ field: "RS_LookBackDays", title: "Rate Schedule – # Lookback Days", type: "number" },
```

I have a custom client-side filtering on a property that is bound to a text box which is then applied to the dataSource on the click of a search button.

```
if (ctrl.selectedRS_LookBackDays && ctrl.selectedRS_LookBackDays != '') {
    var filter = { field: "RS_LookBackDays", operator: "eq", value: ctrl.selectedRS_LookBackDays };
    filters.push(filter);
}

ctrl.kendoGrid.dataSource.filter(filters);
```

There are other filters being applied on 'string' columns which execute successfully and filter the grid data. However, for numeric columns I get a client-side error message : '**TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'toLowerCase'**". I am unable to get this work even though I have specified the type on the column as well as the grid.

Answer (score 1):

Solved It. I just had to use the below code:

```
 var filter = { field: "RS_LookBackDays", operator: "eq", value: kendo.parseInt(ctrl.selectedRS_LookBackDays) };
```

So silly ! ;)